# Configure the Ethernet Interface from the Command Line

Tags: networking, unix, ip, ethernet, ifconfig

I have connected to a Virtual Server with an SSH client using IP address: 172.xx.xx.154/22

I have been asked to configure eth1 to 172.xx.xx.155/24 with gateway IP Address of: 172.xx.xx.1

Any help would be welcome as I am a relative novice when it comes networking with Unix.

Comment: Does it mean that eth1 should have a static IP address?

Comment: -1: The question shows very little (if any) research effort.

Comment: Well I have tried to do this on numerous occasions using different commands and messed it up. Here is what I think the solution is through my research; ifconfig eth1 172.xx.xx.155 netmask 255.255.255.0 Then add this command to script in /etc called rc.local, so that it will not get overwritten by other scripts. Then  use the ifconfig command to activate the interface, ifconfig eth1 up. Finally configure the gateway IP that the system should use using the route command. Route add default gw 172.xx.xx.1. Also adding this line in the rc.local script.

Comment: What variant of Linux do you use - the "ideal" solution differs depending on your distro - in Redhat like systems you create/edit a file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts while in debian like systems you edit /etc/network/intgerfaces - and then use the appropriate network service scripts to reload.  (Loading into rc.local can work but is a hack)

Comment: Having run the following command; cat /etc/*release . I can see that the variant of Linux I am using is CentOS 6.2. Which is Red Hat Linux Distribution.

Answer (score 0):

see this document on configuring NICS on FreeBSD http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/config-network-setup.html

you can use [ifconfig(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ifconfig&sektion=8) to configure the interface, but the article above discusses how to persist those settings across reboots in your  /etc/rc.conf.